# How can I use map.KeySet() in sql query in java

Tags: java, dictionary, keyset

I have a LinkedHahMap **map1** whcih holds **key** as my **beam_current** which is of double type and value as my logtime which is of string type.
Now I want to use this map1.keySet() in my sql query as-

```
Set<Double> arr=    map1.keySet();
String vs2="select b.beam_current, b.beam_energy where
          b.logtime between '"+first+"' and '"+last+"' and b.beam_current in('"+arr+"')";
```

But when I use **arr** which **holds value of map1 key** ,**nothing is being displayed.**Can't we use map1.KeySet() method in sql query or I'm implemting it in wrong way??

Comment: '"+arr+"' == arr.toString() == [1,2,3] == .beam_current in('[1,2,3]')";

Comment: You should produce a proper string list of values or override the toString , but please don't use this kind of queries build without parameters, they are prone to SQL injection... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Answer (score 2):

First convert your map keys into comma separated string and then use it in your query.

```
  List<Double> slist = new ArrayList<Double>(map1.keySet());
  String s = StringUtils.join(slist, ',');


      String vs2="select b.beam_current, b.beam_energy where
                  b.logtime between '"+first+"' and '"+last+"' and    
                  b.beam_current in('"+s+"')";
```

Comment: what is slist??Is it d??

Comment: @atsih ,I can't see your  edit and when I implement thsi i get an exception **Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<Double> to List<Double>** and moreover another Exception **StringUtils cannot be resolved** occurs

Comment: I have edited my answer changed `HashSet` to `ArrayList` and slist is instance of `List`, please let me know if you have any issue. check line number 1 in answer

Comment: what do to about StringUtils,as It can't be resolved.

Comment: It is form `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` you have to add `commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar` jar file

Comment: I did but getting an exception **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type varchar to real**

Comment: print `s` in your project and check that, is it coming comma separated string?

Comment: its coming comma separated. But why no values are being printed?What is this conversion error??

Comment: actually your main issue is resolved it's another issue, ask it as new issue and close this question by accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depend on external libs (like StringUtils.join), you can do it manually:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Double, String> map1 = new HashMap<Double, String>();
    map1.put(1.5, "");
    map1.put(2.5, "");
    String first = "first";
    String last = "last";

    String query = buildQuery(map1, first, last);
    System.out.println(query);
}

private static String buildQuery(HashMap<Double, String> map1, String first, String last) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select b.beam_current, b.beam_energy where b.logtime between '");
    sb.append(first);
    sb.append("' and '");
    sb.append(last);
    sb.append("' and b.beam_current in (");
    String separator = "";
    for (Double val : map1.keySet()) {
        sb.append(separator);
        sb.append(val);
        separator = ", ";
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```